# Get dynamic colors in highcharts js for more graph highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have those colors that I fix in highcharts.js. 
colors:"#FF9933, #7CB5EC, #F7786B, #FFF200, #bbccdd, #F7CAC9, #F7786B, #91A8D0, #034F84, #FAE03C, #98DDDE, #9896A4, #DD4132, #B1A36A, #79C753"

How can I  get dynamic different colors from highcharts.js for more graph? Give me some suggest!

Comment: Where you want to have different colors, how do you want to show them on your chart and what do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: For example, I have 4 column charts, each of them has one stack column, I want get dynamic 4 different colors for them! Ex: Charts 1: color of column is #FF9933, Charts 2: color of column is #7CB5EC, ...

Comment: You should be able to add your colors inside your series and inside your points: http://jsfiddle.net/cvLs35d7/ if this example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz Blachliński, but your example  won't meet exactly my requirement. I have found solution to get dynamic colors for more charts! I do like that : colors:[Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], colors:[Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]], .... :)